# iOS - UITableViewCell not displaying check mark after being selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make a UITableView that adds a checkmark to a selected cell, what happens is that it does add the checkmark but not immediately, it shows it when I select a different row. Any idea how I can make it be instantaneous? This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Contact";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"TwitterFriend.screen_name"]);
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"TwitterFriend.screen_name"];
    if ([self.selectedContacts containsObject:[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.selectedContacts addObject:[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: You could try putting that logic in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: What? You know you pasted the same method twice right? :P

Comment: Omg I just noticed that I was using the wrong methods, that's what I get for trusting the autocomplete. Thanks dude. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're performing your logic in `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, but by default, this method isn't called until the cell selection changes. If you instead put it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (note the slightly different name), you'll get the callback as soon as the cell is tapped, and the accessory view should appear immediately.